# React Context provider doesn't see data

Tags: reactjs

I need to parse data from modal window (Modalbuy.js) to parent component (Page.js) and then to another child, but my Context Provider doesn't see changed data.Despite that fact, if I ask to console.log not in context.provider brackets, but still in parent component, I get my data logs right

Modalbuy.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./modal.css";
import { DataBuyContext } from "../../page/page";


const Modalbuy = ({active, setActive,price}) => {
  const [inputVolume, setInputVolume] = useState("")
  function saveInput(event) {
    setInputVolume(event.target.value)
    console.log(inputVolume)
  }

  const {dataBuy, setDataBuy} = React.useContext(DataBuyContext)
  function addBuy() {
    setDataBuy([...dataBuy,{side: "BUY", price:{price},volume: {inputVolume},timestamp: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}])
    // console.log(dataBuy)
  }


  
  
    return (
      
      
        <div className={active ? "modal active" : "modal"} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
          <div className="modal__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <header>Make order</header>
            <p>BUY {price}</p>
            <input placeholder="Volume" value={inputVolume} onChange={saveInput}></input>
            <div>
              <button onClick = {addBuy}>Ok</button>
              <button onClick={() => setActive(false)} >Cancel</button>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
        
        
    )
}

export default Modalbuy;
```

Page.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'


import Trading from '../trading/Trading'
import Archive from '../archive/Archive'
import './page.css';
export const DataBuyContext = React.createContext({})



const Page = () => {

  const [dataBuy, setDataBuy] = useState([{}])
  


  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1)

  const toggleTab = (index) =>{
    setToggleState(index);
  }
  console.log(dataBuy)
  



  return (
    <DataBuyContext.Provider value = {{dataBuy, setDataBuy}}>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="block-tabs">
        <button
          className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
          onClick={() => toggleTab(1)}>
          Trading
        </button>
        <button
          className={toggleState === 2 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
          onClick={() => toggleTab(2)}>
          Archive
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="content-tabs">
        <div
          className={toggleState === 1 ? "content  active-content" : "content"}>
            <Trading />

          
        </div>

        <div
          className={toggleState === 2 ? "content  active-content" : "content"}>
            <Archive dataBuy= {dataBuy} />

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </DataBuyContext.Provider>
  );

}

export default Page;
```

And Archive.js child component, where I want to transport data

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './archive.css';
import Table from './Table';




const Archive = (dataBuy) => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(dataBuy)
    console.log(rows)


    return (

        <Table dataBuy = {rows}/>
        
       

        
    )
  }

  export default Archive;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Page from './components/page/page'


function App() {

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Page/>

    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Also, in Page.js in console.log I get 2 objects: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0
: 
{}
1
: 
{side: 'BUY', price: {…}, volume: {…}, timestamp: '09:32:45'}
length
: 
2
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0), where first object is empty for some reason. I don't know if this is the reason it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post your `App` component?

Comment: There is kinda nothing special in App.js

Comment: Can't see where you use <Modalbuy/> component. The problem is, probably, Modalbuy is not a child of DataBuyContext.Provider. But then, you would receive error like `setDataBuy is not a function`.

You have empty object because you specified it while initializing state: `const [dataBuy, setDataBuy] = useState([{}])`

Comment: Well I did get this kind of error a couple of times. How it can be fixed tho? I have no idea for example :/

Comment: @shvedd02 You should wrap your `App` into `DataBuyContext.Provider` to access its values globally

Comment: So, in Table.js, dataBuy argument is equal to my object, but when I assign {buyData} = dataBuy, buyData is undefined. Why is it undefined?

Comment: About DataBuyContext.Provider, Page component still wraps all my components, will it actually make any difference?